# Preventing decompiling of applet

Tags: java, applet, decompiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it worth to obfuscate java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419474/is-it-worth-to-obfuscate-java-web-application)

I have writen an applet. I don't want other people to decompile it using easily availabe decompilers. I have taken lots of pains to implemented the code. Can anyone suggest how I can protect my applet from geting decompiled?

Comment: there is only one failsafe way - do not distribute your applet :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always try to use an *obfuscator* like [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) or [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html), but resistance if almost always futile.

With a proper tool, like [Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/), and enough time and expertise, your code will be broken.

Comment: This. If your code is worth decompiling, it will be.

Answer (score 2):

Consider whether you're wasting your time with obfuscation. It costs time and money and usually doesn't protect the code against anyone really determined to decompile it.

Instead make your applet better and better, because that would mean someone would have to decompile it again and again and eventually, they will just use your code because it's easier ... as long as it **is** easier. If you applet sucks, someone else will come up with a better one and you will loose, no matter how you "protect" your code.

Read [Getting Real](http://gettingreal.37signals.com/) and [Rework](http://37signals.com/rework/) on how to make your applet better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Obfuscation](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~collberg/Research/Students/DouglasLow/obfuscation.html).

---

**On the same topic :**

- [How to protect compiled Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443542/how-to-protect-compiled-java-classes)
- [How to lock compiled Java Classes to prevent decompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation)
- [Is Java Code obfuscation actually effective vs decompilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242055/is-java-code-obfuscation-actually-effective-vs-decompilers)
- [Making commercial Java software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466424/making-commercial-java-software)