# How can protect Java source code

Tags: java, web-applications, war, source-code-protection

I am developing an `Java web application` witch I will `deploy` to a `war` file.

The problem is that using `JD Decompiler` system administrators or someone else witch has access to war file can decompile and take the source code. 
Is it possible to protect the source code of `JAVA` ?

For `.Net` application I use `Intellilock` to lock my `C# source code` and it works fine. But for `Java` it does not work.

Comment: Does the users have access to your war file? I mean, do they have access to the webserver filesystem to retrieve that war file and decompile it?

Comment: Google "java obfuscation", or search on stackoverflow for "[java] obfuscation".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379/how-to-lock-compiled-java-classes-to-prevent-decompilation

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088/do-you-obfuscate-your-commercial-java-code