# Protect .Net application from Deobfuscators?

Tags: .net, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I know that we can protect .Net applications from decompiling by using obfuscators.

But I read somewhere that there is some Deobfuscators (like de4dot ) that can deobfuscate .Net obfuscated applications. They can Neutralize the effect of some obfuscators like Eazfuscator.NET . So, they can decompile even obfuscated .Net applications.

Is that right? If yes, how to protect applications from deobfuscators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No app is 100% protected, but the commercial obfuscators make a pretty good job of making it hard.

Comment: Can you say the name of some of these commercial obfuscators that making deobfuscate much harder? And what about free obfuscators? Aren't they safe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195/should-you-obfuscate-a-commercial-net-application

Comment: Can I use some obfuscators together? will this increase security?

Comment: You would have to talk to the producers of them

Answer (score 4):

In short, you can't. You can only make life difficult for people, but ultimately, if they want to access your code, they can do.

Comment: But this process is much harder in c++ compiler. is this mean that we should not make valuable programs with .Net ?

Answer (score 1):

Use an obfuscator to prevent this - obfuscators change the structure but **not** the meaning/intent of your source code so as to make it very hard for a cracker/hacker to understand the code. Take a look at [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) which employs various techniques like symbol renaming, string encryption, control flow obfuscation, etc.

It also has special defenses against de4dot - if you try to run de4dot on assemblies obfuscated with Crypto Obfuscator, it will crash.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of Crypto Obfuscator.

Comment: Looks like he's onto you: https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot/wiki/Changelog

Comment: @CADbloke - Its like an arms race - we are onto him too.

Comment: But every time they crack it then everything you've obfuscated is vulnerable, so you only get to cloak new IP, until the next round. Or am I missing something here? Genuine question.

Comment: You have a defense for this in 218?

Answer (score 0):

Why not? You can try [ILProtector](http://www.vgrsoft.com/en/products/ilp). It is free .NET protector. It protects .NET code using code virtualization. In this case level of code protection increases manyfold compared to obfuscation. Your code is not recognized by disassemblers and decompilers such as de4dot, IL DASM or .NET Reflector.

Comment: Will it decrease the performance of application?

Comment: I didn't check, but i think it will change insignificantly if at all

Comment: Looks like he cracked that one too: https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot/wiki/Changelog ... v1.9.0

Comment: ILProtector encrypts method instructions. This is NOT virtualization. This is banal Code Encryption, just like in any other protector. It looks like the feature is called virtualization just because it sounds trendy for the author.