# Log4net outputting random method names after applciation is obfuscated via .net -reactor

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, log4net, obfuscation, net-reactor

I have obfuscated my application using .net reactor. Application is working fine other then on some places method names in log file created through log4net is coming as random string.
Strange thing is within same method different logs are coming with different behavior. Some coming with actual method name while other with random method name.
e.g,

My log4net appender is

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="..\\Logs\\MyApp_N1" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="_yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}&#9;%p&#9;MyApp&#9;N1&#9;%t&#9;%c{1}.%M&#9;%property{SessionId}&#9;%m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

log4net version 2.0.8
.net reactor version 5.0

Sample Log Messages are

2017-12-08 15:17:33.722 DEBUG   TWS N1  13      MyclassName.SendMessage             My method start

2017-12-08 15:17:33.840 DEBUG   TWS N1  13      MyclassName.urT1VHsGarQ1gTcc8O      Message request add in db id =166364

2017-12-08 15:17:33.852 DEBUG   TWS N1  13      MyclassName.SendMessage             Message Services - Send End

Comment: Seems as expected. All non-public method names were obfuscated, all public method names are not touched.

Comment: @Evk Within same method there are 3 lines of logs. Two are coming with actual method name while one is coming with random method name. Isn't this looks like a inconsistent behavior.

Comment: See Blair comments on this answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195/should-you-obfuscate-a-commercial-net-application

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo Guirelli de Queiroz. Let me check it

Comment: Is method in question uses async await or yield return statement? Is it public?

Comment: It's a public method and not using async/await/yield

Answer (score 0):

If the method 'urT1VHsGarQ1gTcc8O' is not a public one then this is the expected output.

To obfuscate all public classes and methods as well you need to set "2. Protection Settings"->"Obfuscation"->"Obfuscate Public Types" to "True".