# What can be done to secure JAR files besides obfuscation?

Tags: java, classloader, obfuscation, decompiling, copy-protection

I'm concerned about the security of Java executables. They offer little protection against decompilation. With tools like Java Decompiler even a kid can decompile the class files to get the original code.

Apart from code obfuscation what can be done to protect a class file?  Is the Encrypted Class Loader still a myth?

Comment: Write Open Source Software, and you wont have that problem. :-D

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Why) should I use obfuscation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882/why-should-i-use-obfuscation)

Comment: Write code worth paying for and those that will pay for it will pay, those that wouldn't pay anyway are not a concern.

Answer (score 10):

In a previous company we had such questions, mainly driven by management paranoia.

First of all, you have to understand that absolute security is only a myth: As long as your program is run on untrusted hardware, it *can* be decompiled, no matter what language you use. The only thing you can change is the cost of an attacker to understand your software/algorithm/data.

Concerning obfuscation: it can be considered a first level of protection, as it makes the Java code totally unreadable.  Good obfuscators like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) use forbidden characters in variables/methods names, preventing execution of decompiled code. Now, one can consider it a good enough security measure, as decompiling code is *not* as simple as running Jad or other decompilers and having perfectly working Java code. However, it is possible to understand most of the algorithms exposed in such code (as *readable* code is very different from *compilable* code).

Additional security measures include:

- Running sensitive code on a server by using some kind of web-service to send results and grab results (using REST/SOAP/YouNameIt)
- Loading sensitive code from a remote server using HTTPS and (maybe) additional security layers.

From those two security measures, I would honestly choose the first. Indeed, the second can be subverted by typical HTTPS attacks (man in the middle, logging proxies, and so on, ...), and has the *major* inconvenience of putting the code on untrusted hardware, which makes it possibly borrowable from there.

Comment: We too had such a requirement by paranoid managment. The proposed solution is to go full web app instead of desktop. A thin client can be made from java if absolutely required but I personally spend the effort into a web 2.0 interface.

Comment: @Pierre In our case, it was an advanced trading application, which required huge amounts of displays, totally unthinkable (from my Java/Swing developper history at least) using even the best HTML5 sub-technologies (I mean, even SVG at its best won't do the job, without even thinking about the browser ecosystem hell)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are four things you can do with your bytecode to protect it against Java decompilers:

- obfuscation
- software encryption
- hardware encryption
- native compilation

all covered in my article [Protect Your Java Code - Through Obfuscators And Beyond](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write all your code with in `native`. The reverse engineering can be done anyway. But is harder.

Ok, this is not a strictly java solution.

As nfechner said in a comment write open source application.