# Can some one get jar from a docker image and reverse engineer the jar to get the source code?

Tags: java, docker, jar

I was curious could anybody get the jar from a docker image and reverse engineer to the source code.
What are the better ways to protect the source code when deploying the application jar in the client's local machine.

Comment: As far as I know, Docker images don't provide any extra protection against reverse engineering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can done to secure jar files besides obfuscation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324708/what-can-done-to-secure-jar-files-besides-obfuscation)

Comment: In short, yes.  If that is a problem use licenses or contracts to secure your intellectual property.