# D365 - Which is the best tool to obfuscate the CRM plug-in (c#) code?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

D365 - Which is the best tool to obfuscate the CRM plug-in (c#) code?

Comment: Please Be Precise!

Answer (score 0):

*Arguably this question is dangerously close to being [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#), however; in this case I feel I can address some elements without being entirely off-topic.*

As far as I know there is no 'best tool' to obfuscate code *specifically* for a CRM plugin.

A CRM plugin is just C# complied into a .Net assembly. You could probably select your obfuscation tool as you would for any other .Net development.

It's worth considering that a CRM plug-in has to meet a public interface, so whatever tool you use needs to respect that interface. Furthermore, elements of the plugin (e.g. name) can be seen within the CRM user interface, you may want to considered not obfuscating those elements.

I'm guessing that your end goal is to publically release a plugin, it's worth remebering that obfuscation doesn't provide security or licence enforcement.

Further reading:

- [The case for code obfuscation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129296/the-case-for-code-obfuscation)
- [Is .NET code obfuscation really worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314513/is-net-code-obfuscation-really-worth-it)
- [Is obfuscation worth it](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107025/is-obfuscation-worth-it)

Comment: Nothing to argue - it fits the definition of off-topic to the letter: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic "